# Mysql restore database through stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, restore

I want to restore mysql database through stored procedure? Is it possible?

Or can I copy dbfile and rename that folder?

Please let me know if anyone needs more information to answer this question.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Manasi

Comment: It look strange for me to restore a database in a stored procedure.
But in any case, you have to be more clear : which version of MySQL ? which OS ?...

Comment: Hi. I am using 5.1.30-ndb-6.3.20-cluster-gpl on Linux-Fedora10 64 bit.

Well I am needing to create db and its tables at runtime. I can do this through script but it takes time for procedure to execute so I want a workaround. Either by restoring it or else I have one sample db created I just want to make copy of the same with different names. Is it possible??

Comment: Does anyone know any solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "restore:"

The only way you could restore a database using a stored procedure is if the backup is accessible via SQL, so the data would have to be contained in some tables accessible from the stored procedure.  In that case, it's a simple matter of writing the SQL to copy the data from the tables of one database to the tables of another using a handful of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statements.

It isn't possible to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` in a stored procedure, so you can't pull in a raw data dump, and there's no way (in MySQL, at least) to execute a script residing on disk, so a dump from mysqldump wouldn't work.

You certainly can't move files and folders around from a stored procedure; you should never do that while MySQL is running.

Comment: Thanks for your response James.